# How to implement stacked notifications

Tags: android

I'm looking at [this code in the Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Managing) for stacking notifications:

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
...
```

but I don't understand how you can keep track of the `numMessages` parameter across multiple receipts from GCM or how you can start a "loop that processes data" as they say in comments.  I would think you would need to retrieve any current notifications and then append the new data to them.  Any help appreciated.

edit: I also don't understand what the point of iterating over the loop would be if each notification overwrites the last one, why not just send a notification for the last iteration of this loop?

Comment: Did you solve your problems? If so, how? I was wondering about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
new Notification.Builder().setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(false);
```

Good luke!

Comment: This will only make a notification that persists, but I still don't know how to process multiple GCM RECEIVE intents.

Answer (score 0):

`mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);`//automatically canceled when the user clicks it
 `mBuilder.setOngoing(true);`/*if true:
Ongoing notifications differ from regular notifications in the following ways:

Ongoing notifications are sorted above the regular notifications in the notification panel.
    Ongoing notifications do not have an 'X' close button, and are not affected by the "Clear all" button. */